# When I archive my app: Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I archive my app the following error occurs:

```
XABLD7000: Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied
   bei Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipArchive.Close() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/ZipArchive.cs:Zeile 874.
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ZipArchiveEx.Flush()
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.ExecuteWithAbi(String[] supportedAbis, String apkInputPath, String apkOutputPath, Boolean debug, Boolean compress, IDictionary`2 compressedAssembliesInfo)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.RunTask()
   bei Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:Zeile 17.
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried to achieve other app? Will the same problem occur?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No, only occurs on this App

Comment: Is it convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. In my scenario, 1. I had first archived an myapp.aab
2. I changed my bundle from myapp.aab to myapp.apk. and that is when i faced this error archiving an apk app.

Solution
I closed my project (visual studio), went to my project folder, deleted bin & obj. Then i reopened my visual studion(project), tried archiving and it worked out.